# How can I fix "Invalid URLS error" when using SpringBoot adapter and KeyCloak with AWS Application Load Balancer?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, keycloak, aws-application-load-balancer

Hi I am having a problem with SSL termination for SpringBoot adapter and KeyCloak. I am using **KeyCloak    15.1.1**

Before implementing SSL, everything works fine with HTTP. The headache comes when I implemented SSL.

I get Invalid URLS error at when trying to load using HTTPS. I am able to load the front end web pages, but the API calls are not working.

**AWS APPLICATION LOAD BALANCER DETAILS**

I am using AWS Application Load balancer to **with ACM Certificate** to allow https request over http.  My Application Load balancer has a **https:443 listener** to forwards all https request (port 443) to http. This https listener has the rule :

- if path is app/api* forward to target group **http:8081**

The Load Balancer DNS name and  the ACM certificate are already registered at Route 53 Hosted Zones:

- Record Type A
- RecordName : myapp.com
- Routing: Simple
- Alias: Yes
- Value/Traffice routed to: **myapp-alb-xxxxxxxxx..amazonaws.com** (this is the app load balancer DNS Name)
- The ACM Certificate is created using my website's domain name (myapp.com)

**AWS CLOUD VM**

Inside my AWS EC2 Cloud VM, I have Angular, Spring boot, and Keycloak running

- Spring boot Server is running Port 8081
- KeyCloak Server running in port 8080

In my angular API configuration, I have set all API endpoints to use **https://myapp.com/app/api** :

```
  apiConfig: {
    api1tEndpoint: 'https://myapp.com/app/api/api1',
    api2Endpoint: 'https://myapp.com/app/api/api2,
  },
```

At The Springboot backend, the keycloak configuration are set in the application.proprties :

```
server.port=8081

# KEYCLOAK Configuration
keycloak.enabled=true
keycloak.realm=MyAppRealm
**keycloak.auth-server-url=https://mayapp.com/auth
keycloak.ssl-required=none
```

In the KeyCloak standalone.xml, I have set the following based on this article I read [here](https://wjw465150.gitbooks.io/keycloak-documentation/content/server_installation/topics/clustering/load-balancer.html) :

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:12.0">
    <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http"
        proxy-address-forwarding="true" redirect-socket="proxy-https"/>
</subsystem>
:
:
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public"
    port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
    ...
    <socket-binding name="proxy-https" port="443"/>
    ...
</socket-binding-group>
```

**QUESTIONS:**

1. Is there any configuration I missed in my Spring Boot App or at Angular?
2. For Keycloak, did I do the correct configuration? Or I need to configure somewhere else besides standalone.xml?
3. Or Is my configuration at AWS Load balancer done correctly?